# What statistical tests do online AB test calculators use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, ab-test

I'm studying various statistical tests related to AB testing for businesses - Fisher's exact test, student's t-test, etc.

As I was doing so, I remembered the various convenient online AB testing calculators that let people punch in a few data points and output a p-value and "winner" version. For example -

[image]

- https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/ab-testing-significance-calculator/
- https://abtestguide.com/calc/
- abtestcalculator.com
- ...

There are so many of them. I wondered, what statistical tests are behind those calculators? Is there a more popular one among all of the calculators?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both links you provided (Survey Monkey and AB Testguide) are just one-sided z-tests for a difference in proportions. Survey Monkey doesn't provide the formula, but you can easily verify it by trying the calculations yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Doctor Milt! Do you know why they don't use z score instead of t test here? I'm guessing in t test, you'd need to know the sample variances whereas in the z score calculation, you don't necessarily need variances?

Comment: It _is_ a z-test rather than a t-test. 

The Central Limit Theorem tells us that the sample proportions are approximately Normally distributed when the sample sizes are large.

Comment: sorry I meant the opposite... why don't they use t-test? Thanks for your help @Doctor Milt

Comment: The 2-sample t-test is appropriate when comparing the means of two normal populations with unknown (but equal) variances.

In this example our populations are Bernoulli; each visitor becomes a conversion with probability $p$. We write $X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p)$.

We then use the fact that the distribution of $\bar{X}$ is approximately $ \mathrm{N}(p, p(1-p)/n)$ when $n$ is large to construct an (apprximate) z-test.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of it from distribution's perspective before and i just spent some time to think about your comment. It pushed me to understand it much better. thanks for this, @Doctor Milt!